# Flag Behaving Unexpectedly

Tags: rendering, 3d-view, physics, cloth-simulation, cache

I have a flag waving in my blender file. The other flag is working perfectly fine while this one is showing unexpected behavior.

The cube is on 385.4 on x-axis. Also, I've already tried to add another plane and change the existing one, but it shows the same abnormal behavior. In the original file I had 65 of them. 64 of them are working perfectly fine except for this one.

Here is the blender file:

[image]

Comment: Hello Talha.. this looks like a slip.. Cloth > Shape > Pin needs to be set to the vertex group:  'Group' . Unlike @Taio, I didn't bother to figure out why it wasn't flying.. I just Shift-D copied over  the working flag to the right place, modifiers and all, and reparented it.

Comment: Yes, it solved the problem. I actually did a lot of things so forgot to change it back to 200 but could have figured it out. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The flag `Plane.063` has two different settings.

First, it has not its pin group set which will hold the flag in place. Select `Plane.063`, go to the *Physics Properties* panel and then to *Cloth > Shape > Pin Group* and set the vertex group `Group`. Now the flag will stay in place but not wave due to the wind settings.

Second, in the same panel, go to *Cloth > Field Weights > Wind* and set this value to $200$ (thats the value from the working flag `Plane.064`. The flag should wave now again.